# How to convert this date format "Sun Jul 13 2014 00:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" into a standard format "YYYY-m-d" using php

Tags: php, date, date-format, date-conversion

How to convert date format Sun Jul 13 2014 00:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) to  "YYYY-m-d"?

Comment: You need an answer which could be easily acquired by reading the documentation, you should read the PHP's docs and then report your results here in case of failure

Comment: There's a lot of moving parts in [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).  Does anyone here actually know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [strftime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) and [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) functions like this:

```
strftime("%Y-%m-%d", strtotime("Sun Jul 13 2014 00:30:00 GMT+0530"))
```

Comment: Do not hesitate to mark this answer as accepted to improve readability.